# SQL Server 2008 Agent Error login faild Error 18456 Cuando intento Correr un Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo varios job pero cuando intento ejecutarlos o se ejecutan a las horas programadas me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error, e cambiado el modo de autenticacion a mixto pero el error perciste ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es el error que me presenta, gracias agredeceria la ayuda

Comment: ¿Las credenciales del usuario `ITAMARACA\GEA-PALM$` es correcta y/o tiene los permisos suficientes?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave no los tiene, porque si los tuviera, no estaria diciendo que no puedo logear el usuario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tenia que en la configuración de sql server indicarle que no utilize el usuario por defecto si no uno en especifico, gracias

Comment: Por favor recuerda [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.